# Upload directory and files to FTP in Windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

I'm writing a batch script for a Windows 7 machine. The goal of the script is to move files from the directory `C:\directory\source_dir\`  to an ftp server `ftpserver.domain.com`.

Not all the files should be uploaded to the ftp server, so I'm using regular expression.

**File Structure:**

> C:\directory\source_dir\TF_directory1
> C:\directory\source_dir\TF_directory1\file1.txt
> C:\directory\source_dir\TF_directory1\file2.txt
> C:\directory\source_dir\TF_directory1\sub_dir\file_A.txt
> C:\directory\source_dir\Ignore_directory\not_important.txt
> C:\directory\source_dir\TF_123.CAM555.abc
> C:\directory\source_dir\TF_123.CAM123.zyx
> C:\directory\source_dir\TF_987.CAM555.abc
> C:\directory\source_dir\wrong_file.txt

From the above structure `TF_directory1` and everything inside should be uploaded. As should the files `TF_123.CAM555.abc`, `TF_123.CAM123.zyx` and `TF_987.CAM555.abc`.

Here's my problem:

The `ftp put` command returns an error on the directory

```
connected to ftpserver.domain.com
220 Welcome to the ftp server
ftp> user USERNAME
331 Please specify the password

---> PASS PASSWORD
230 Login successful.
ftp>
ftp> cd new_files
250 Directory successfully changed.
---> CWD new_files
ftp> put C:\directory\source_dir\"TF_123.CAM555.abc"
---> PORT 10,X,X,X,4,240
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
---> STOR TF_123.CAM555.abc
150 Ok to send data.
226 File receive OK.
ftp> put C:\directory\source_dir\TF_123.CAM123.zyx"
---> PORT 10,X,X,X,4,240
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
---> STOR TF_123.CAM555.abc
150 Ok to send data.
226 File receive OK.
ftp> put C:\directory\source_dir\TF_987.CAM555.abc"
---> PORT 10,X,X,X,4,240
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
---> STOR TF_123.CAM555.abc
150 Ok to send data.
226 File receive OK.
ftp> put C:\directory\source_dir\"TF_directory1"
**Error opening local file C:\directory\source_dir\TF_directory1.**
ftp> quit
---> QUIT
221 Goodbye.
```

**Script:**

```
set base_dir=C:\directory\
set log_dir=%base_dir%source_dir\
set log_file=%base_dir%log_file.txt

::Function to check if the ftpinfo exists. If not, create it.
:createFTPinfoFile
echo ########################## entering function :createFTPinfoFile
if not exist %base_dir%ftpinfo.dat (
    echo %timestamp% -- Creating ftpinfo.dat file at location %base_dir% >> %log_file%
    echo user USERNAME> %base_dir%ftpinfo.dat
    echo PASSWORD>> %base_dir%ftpinfo.dat
    echo %timestamp% -- Created ftpinfo.dat >> %log_file%
) ELSE (
    echo %timestamp% -- %base_dir%ftpinfo.dat was not properly removed - Removing the file >> %log_file%
    del %base_dir%ftpinfo.dat
    echo %timestamp% -- Creating ftpinfo.dat file at location %base_dir% >> %log_file%
    echo user USERNAME> %base_dir%ftpinfo.dat
    echo PASSWORD >> %base_dir%ftpinfo.dat
    echo %timestamp% -- Created ftpinfo.dat >> %log_file%
)
echo ############################ finished :createFTPinfoFile
EXIT /B 0

:addFilesToFTPinfo 
echo ############################ entering function :addFilesToFTPinfo
set num=0
echo %timestamp% -- Starting to add files from %log_dir% to ftpinfo.dat >> %log_file%
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('forfiles /p %log_dir% /m "TF_*.CAM*.*" /d -0 -c "cmd /c echo put %log_dir%@file >> %base_dir%ftpinfo.dat & echo 1" ^| find /c /v ""') do set /a num=%%i-1
echo %timestamp% -- Starting to add folders from %log_dir% to fptinfo.dat >> %log_file%
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('forfiles /p %log_dir% /m "TF_*" /d -0 /c "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE echo put %log_dir%@file >> %base_dir%ftpinfo.dat & echo 1" ^| find /c /v ""') do set /a num=%num%+%%i-1
echo %timestamp% -- added everything to ftpinfo.dat >> %log_file%
echo ############################ finished :addFilesToFTPinfo
EXIT /B 0

REM::This function creates the connection to the ftp server using the information from ftpinfo.dat
:ftpUploadFiles
echo ########################## entering function :ftpUploadFiles
if exist %base_dir%ftpinfo.dat (
    echo cd new_files >> %base_dir%ftpinfo.dat
    CALL :addFilesToFTPinfo
    echo quit >> %base_dir%ftpinfo.dat
    echo %timestamp% -- Connecting to FTP server to upload files >> %log_file%
    ftp -n -s:%base_dir%ftpinfo.dat ftpserver.domain.com
)
echo ########################## finished :ftpUploadFiles
EXIT /B 0
```

Does anyone know a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows command-line `ftp.exe` client does not support recursive operations.

If you want to transfer folders, you have three options:

1. Do all the hard work in the batch file, generating `ftp` upload commands for all files and folders. While doeable, this is pretty difficult to implement.
2. Use an ad-hoc solution for your specific folder(s), like the answer by @SamDenty shows.
3. Easiest is to use a 3rd party command-line FTP client. Most 3rd party FTP clients do support recursive operations.

---

For example with [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/), you can use a script like:

```
open ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/
put TF_directory1
put TF_123.CAM555.abc
put TF_123.CAM123.zyx
put TF_987.CAM555.abc
exit
```

And run the script (`ftp.txt`) from a batch file like:

```
winscp.com /script=ftp.txt
```

See the [guide for converting Windows FTP script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score 0):

You are using `put` to transfer a folder, but `put` doesn't support transferring folders, only files as stated by:

> **Error opening local **file** C:\directory\source_dir\TF_directory1**

Instead of using `put`, try using:

```
mkdir TF_directory1
cd TF_directory1
mput C:\directory\source_dir\TF_directory1\*
```

Which would:

1. **Make a directory** on the FTP server named *TF_directory1*
2. **CD into the directory**
3. **Copy all files** from the *TF_directory1* and place them in the new FTP folder

Reference -
[Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/133380/use-mput-to-transfer-a-directory-using-ftp)